# Virtual host control system for PHP websites

Tags: web-services, web-apis, web-hosting-control-panel

I need a tool that will allow automatically configure and start apache or nginx virtual hosts for users based on their username from my custom web application. We have a lot of students that at some point of their institution need to upload their PHP applications somewhere public, and of course the database and the user should also be created automatically. So ideally it should be something from this list http://www.tecmint.com/web-control-panels-to-manage-linux-servers/ that has an API to automate things.

Virtual hosts can be subdomains like bob.student.example.com or subdirectories student.example.com/alice, subdomains are preferred if it is possible to automate the DNS record creation via API. We also need to backup the files and databases.

In case if you are sure that there is no application that meets all this requirements, please give me an advice how can I start different apache virtual hosts as a processes of different users, to be sure that nobody can remove files of other users.

Comment: Have you used [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), Try that and come back to edit the question.